# Problem forking processes and creating threads

Tags: pthreads, fork

My program is supposed to fork three processes. Each of these processes will create three threads and fork two additional processes. These two additional processes will create three threads.
Here is my code. I've tried to keep things simple with nested loops. I think at some point I might be forking more processes or creating more threads.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *printme(void* Array){
    int *Arr = (int *) Array;
    int len = sizeof(Arr) / sizeof(int);
    if (len == 1){
        printf("I'm thread %d.%d",Arr[0],Arr[1]);
    }
    else if (len == 2){
        printf("I'm thread %d.%d.%d",Arr[0],Arr[1],Arr[2]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void){
    int i, j, k, l;
    int threadLevel1[2];
    int threadLevel2[3];
    printf("\n");   
    for (i = 1 ; i < 4 ; i++){ // Loop to fork the three main processes.
        if (fork() != 0){
            sleep(4);   
        }
        else{
            //The newly forked process will create three threads and fork two additional processes.

            for (j = 1 ; j < 4 ; j++){
                pthread_t t;                
                threadLevel1[0] = i;
                threadLevel1[1] = j;                
                if (pthread_create(&t, NULL, printme, (void*) threadLevel1) != 0){
                    perror("pthread_create");
                    exit(1);
                }   
            }
            for (k = 1; k < 3 ; k++){           
                pid_t a = fork();               
                if (a != 0){
                    sleep(2);

                }
                else if (a == -1){
                    perror("fork"); /* display error message */
                        exit(0); 
                }
                else{
                    for (l = 1 ; l < 4 ; l++){                          
                        pthread_t t;                    
                        threadLevel2[0] = i;
                        threadLevel2[1] = k;
                        threadLevel2[2] = l;    
                        if (pthread_create(&t, NULL, printme, (void*) threadLevel2)!=0)                                                 {
                            perror("pthread_create");
                            exit(1);                        
                        }                       
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Fascinating! Now, what was your question again?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry about the formatting and stuff. First time here. My question is: the last set of threads is not created. I'm supposed to print out a string that lists the thread roots, like "I'm thread 2.3.1". it works for the first set of threads but not the last.

Comment: Nevermind, I've solved it. Sorry for the messy code.

Comment: You must indent your code to look like code -- I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your code here:

```
void *printme(void* Array){
    int *Arr = (int *) Array;
    int len = sizeof(Arr) / sizeof(int);
```

The value `len` will always be the same no matter what is passed in to `printme`. That's because C passes arrays as pointers, not as objects with embedded lengths.